# How to get a 3 parts iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<style>
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>

<iframe src="../admin/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"
                                style="height: 100%;
                                            width: 49%; float: left; " height="60%" width="49%"
                               align="left">

</iframe>
<iframe src="../admin/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"
                                    style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;

                                    width: 49%; " height="60%" width="49%"
                                     align="right">

</iframe>
<iframe src="../levensthein/" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes"
                                    style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;

                                    width: 100%; " height="100%" width="100%">

</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and i would like to get this display :

[image]

for the moment the iframe 3 is too low : 
[image]

[image]

So if you have any idea how i can move up the iframe 3

Comment: For me it works as you intended when I use 3 sample URLs for each frame source, e.g. google.com, bing.com and ibm.com. So is there something in the source for iframe3 (../levensthein/) that is pushing it down? A margin-top or a relative positioning or a visibility hidden element? Or is there something in iframe2 source affecting the position of iframe3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use divs for that. Use a row with 2 columns and then 1 row.